# Parsing the data in a JSON file and converting it to a SQL table

Tags: python, mysql, json

I am working on building a test software as a side project. I have been given questions for the test in a JSON format. I intend to parse the JSON and store it into an SQL table with the following schema:-

```
TABLE NAME - QUESTIONS
QUESTION_NO - INT (PRIMARY KEY) - AUTO_INCREMENT,
QUESTION_DESC - VARCHAR(255),
OPTA - VARCHAR(255),
OPTB - VARCHAR(255),
OPTC - VARCHAR(255),
OPTD - VARCHAR(255),
CORRECTOPT - VARCHAR(1) [Should be 'A','B','C','D']
```

The JSON is in the following format:-

```
[
    {
        "1": "Total number of ATP produced during Kreb's cycle",
        "2": "what is referred to as reference carbohydrate?"
    },
    {
        "1": {
            "a": "8",
            "b": "11",
            "c": "12",
            "d": "36"
        },
        "2": {
            "a": "glucose",
            "b": "glyceraldehde",
            "c": "fructose",
            "d": "lactose"
        }
    },
    {
        "1": "12",
        "2": "glyceraldehyde"
    }
]
```

I initially tried writing a Python code to parse the JSON which is as follows:-

```
import json

with open('BIOset1.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

print(data)
```

Here BIOset1.json is the name of the JSON file I am trying to parse.
But, I get the following error:-

```
raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Can someone please help me to parse this JSON file and retrieve the data in the following format so that I can insert the data into the SQL table?

I come from a non-programming background and I am trying to bring out a genuine change in my university through these questions.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
[{
        "QUESTION_DESC": "Total number of ATP produced during Kreb's cycle",
        "OPTA": "8",
        "OPTB": "11",
        "OPTC": "12",
        "OPTD": "36",
        "CORRECTOPT": "C"
    },
    {
        "QUESTION_DESC": "what is referred to as reference carbohydrate?",
        "OPTA": "glucose",
        "OPTB": "fructose",
        "OPTC": "lactose",
        "OPTD": "aldehyde",
        "CORRECTOPT": "B"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#Create a function that accepts json and outputs the required format 
#code tested on python3
    def format_json(data):
        #solution list
        final_list = []
        ###questions formatting
        ques_desc_1 = data[0].get("1")
        ques_desc_2 = data[0].get("2")
        ###answer
        answ_1 = data[1].get("1")
        answ_2 = data[1].get("2")
        ###correct answers
        corr_1 = data[2].get("1")
        corr_2 = data[2].get("2")
        ####
        #dictionary = for question 1
        dict1 = {"QUESTION_DESC": ques_desc_1,
                 }
        # "CORRECTOPT": data[2].get("1")
        #loop through options available for answer
        option_dict =[]
        for item in answ_1.items():
            #append
            option_dict.append(item)
        dict1.update({
            "OPTA": option_dict[0][1],
            "OPTB": option_dict[1][1],
            "OPTC": option_dict[2][1],
            "OPTD": option_dict[3][1],
        })

        ##
        dict1.update({"CORRECTOPT": dict1.get("OPTC")})

        # dictionary = for question 2
        dict2 = {"QUESTION_DESC": ques_desc_2,
                 }
        # "CORRECTOPT": data[2].get("1")
        # loop through options available for answer
        option_dict2 = []
        for item in answ_2.items():
            # append
            option_dict2.append(item)
        #update
        dict2.update({
            "OPTA": option_dict2[0][1],
            "OPTB": option_dict2[1][1],
            "OPTC": option_dict2[2][1],
            "OPTD": option_dict2[3][1],
        })
        ##
        dict2.update({"CORRECTOPT": dict2.get("OPTC")})
        #########
        final_list.append(dict1)
        final_list.append(dict2)
        ###
        print(final_list)

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        #sample list
        list_dict = [
        {
            "1": "Total number of ATP produced during Kreb's cycle",
            "2": "what is referred to as reference carbohydrate?"
        },
        {
            "1": {
                "a": "8",
                "b": "11",
                "c": "12",
                "d": "36"
            },
            "2": {
                "a": "glucose",
                "b": "glyceraldehde",
                "c": "fructose",
                "d": "lactose"
            }
        },
        {
            "1": "12",
            "2": "glyceraldehyde"
        }]
        #function to format data
        format_json(list_dict)
```

Comment: How can I modify this program to work for n questions instead of just 2 questions?

Answer (score 1):

First, I see no error in your JSON other than you have a spelling error (`"b": "glyceraldehde"`). So there must be some other issue. The following almost does the job:

```
import json

data = """[
    {
        "1": "Total number of ATP produced during Kreb's cycle",
        "2": "what is referred to as reference carbohydrate?"
    },
    {
        "1": {
            "a": "8",
            "b": "11",
            "c": "12",
            "d": "36"
        },
        "2": {
            "a": "glucose",
            "b": "glyceraldehyde",
            "c": "fructose",
            "d": "lactose"
        }
    },
    {
        "1": "12",
        "2": "glyceraldehyde"
    }
]"""

data = json.loads(data)

results = [{"QUESTION_DESC": data[0][k],
            "OPTA": data[1][k]["a"],
            "OPTB": data[1][k]["b"],
            "OPTC": data[1][k]["c"],
            "OPTD": data[1][k]["d"],
            "CORRECTOPT": data[2][k]} for k in data[0].keys()]

for result in results:
    print(result)
```

Prints:

```
{'QUESTION_DESC': "Total number of ATP produced during Kreb's cycle", 'OPTA': '8', 'OPTB': '11', 'OPTC': '12', 'OPTD': '36', 'CORRECTOPT': '12'}
{'QUESTION_DESC': 'what is referred to as reference carbohydrate?', 'OPTA': 'glucose', 'OPTB': 'glyceraldehyde', 'OPTC': 'fructose', 'OPTD': 'lactose', 'CORRECTOPT': 'glyceraldehyde'}
```

The problem is that the value for `CORRECTOP` needs to be changed to the actual option letter that contains that value. So we need a post adjustment:

```
for result in results:
    correctopt = result["CORRECTOPT"]
    for opt in ["A", "B", "C", "D"]:
        if correctopt == result["OPT" + opt]:
            result["CORRECTOPT"] = opt
            break

for result in results:
    print(result)
```

Prints:

```
{'QUESTION_DESC': "Total number of ATP produced during Kreb's cycle", 'OPTA': '8', 'OPTB': '11', 'OPTC': '12', 'OPTD': '36', 'CORRECTOPT': 'C'}
{'QUESTION_DESC': 'what is referred to as reference carbohydrate?', 'OPTA': 'glucose', 'OPTB': 'glyceraldehyde', 'OPTC': 'fructose', 'OPTD': 'lactose', 'CORRECTOPT': 'B'}
```

You can convert this back to JSON with: `json.dumps(result)`